# How to fetch value from input box using jQuery in selenium

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I tried using below code snippet to fetch value from jQuery but it is not getting executed and fails.

```
String actZip = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return $(\"#zip-code\").val()").toString();
System.out.println("zip code value is -->"+actZip);
```

Comment: Hello, did you try using ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById("zip-code").value") instead?

Comment: Hi, I tried this ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('zip-code').value"); But it dint work either.